# How to get the transaction data with Date from First transaction date and Address from latest transaction Date if updated?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to rearrange the data with Date as First transaction/Shopping date and address from latest transaction. The Data consists of transaction of a single customer on various dates. Please help.

[image]

The Desired Out should be like:

[image]

Comment: Please post your desired output. It will be much clearer what has to be done.

Comment: Updated the question with desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Due to lack of table structure etc., here some "dummy" code. The idea is to first evaluate min and max date for each customer and then perform a join between the corresponding records:

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT [Customer Code_Transaction]) AS CustomerCode
        ,min([Invoice Date_Transaction]) AS MinDate
        ,max([Invoice Date_Transaction]) AS MaxDate
    FROM [yourtable...]
    GROUP BY [Customer Code_Transaction]
)
SELECT t1.[Invoice Date_Transaction]
      ,t1.[Customer Code_Transaction]
      ,t1.[Customer Name_Transaction]
      ,t2.[Address_CustReport]
   FROM [yourtable...] AS t1
   JOIN cte AS c ON c.MinDate = t1.[Invoice Date_Transaction] AND c.CustomerCode = t1.[Customer Code_Transaction]
   JOIN [yourtable...] AS t2 ON t2.[Customer Code_Transaction] = c.[Customer Code_Transaction] AND t2.[Invoice Date_Transaction] = c.MaxDate
```